# Breaking 2D Hierarchical Data into a relational database

Tags: excel, database, powerbi

I have the output of SAP that looks like the following:

[image: SAP example Data]

The ObjectName is a field that represents the level that the line is attributed too. The order in this case is important as all those level 5 items belong to level 4 which belong to level 3 etc. I know the manual solution is easy but what I really need to do is link the items together in a tree structure. Ideally a code that the first instance of level 0 = 1 the second is 2 etc. level 1 becomes 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc. Level 3 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3. etc.

This also needs to be repeatable in either DAX or VBA as I would like to build a report with the data regularly, I am a little stumped with the logic behind it.

I am mainly trying to drive some logic to define the relationships in the data lines. The issue is that each line contains level data but the only link between child and parent is the location in the spreadsheet, children are under the parents. In a tree structure as the spreadsheet is about 100k lines long, this becomes a laborious task to do manually.

Any directions to look into would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have two columns - one that would act as a key and another that would point to the parent key. Then you can use DAX functions for handling parent-child hierarchies (`PATH`, `PATHITEM`, etc.).

Look here for here for an example: https://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/

Comment: Cheers, that's perfect for the second part, building the report. I am also trying to drive some logic to build these key tables. The issue is that each line contains level data but the only link between child and parent is the location in the spreadsheet, children are under the parents. Updated main post to reflect this.